# How to add a permanent text which is tappable and editable along with hint, which user can change in EditText of android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I looked on google but didn't find what exactly i am looking for.

I want a edit text to have text or image which i can change by tapping it and selecting new text or image. Also i want hint followed by that text or image.

I tried multiple experiment and was able to add text(by changing selection location and adding text) and image(using drawable addition from android code)

For text :

```
edt.setText("Fixed Text");
Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());
```

Image through XML:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

But when i add text, i won't be able to add hint. In case of image hints get added. Also i want my permanent text and image to be tappable and updatable.

Any help would be really helpful. I want $ to be fixed and tappable, and want to change it to different currency. but want 52.63 to be hint and can be editable by user tap.

**EDIT to give more clarity:**

Example:  i want to add part of the text as permanent and part as hint for example $ 52, so $ is permanent and not editable through user, he can select it through list view by tapping on $, but 52 he can change using android keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about the whole part about the image being placed into the EditText as a hint, but if you wanted to create the $52.63 as a hint in the EditText, all you would have to do is:

```
    edt.setHint("$52.63");
```

in your onCreate() method. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this is a simple way to add a hint to a textEdit. If you wanted the hint to change when the user tapped the screen or something like that, I would look into adding a tap listener of the android component that you desire to be tapped to change the hint, and then modify the hint using the method above.

Comment: That is easy to add, even through XML, but i want to add part of the text as permanent and part as hint for example $ 52, so $ is permanent and not editable through user, he can select it through list view by tapping on $, but 52 he can change using android keyboard. Permanent text should be changeable through list view, which i have implemented.

Comment: Oh I am sorry then, that is above my knowledge of the android platform(which is very little), I have only experimented with small XML layouts that really were just for messing around, I am sorry that I could not be of more assistance

Comment: Thanks for trying to help man. Hopefully this answer will be used by other people who are looking for hint problem.